# Create all possible combinations from 3 different pivot table in the same sheet in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 3 different pivot tables with different data sources in the same sheet and I am trying to create all possible combinations in the another sheet using VBA.I use slicers for every pivot to select the values for every pivot and then i want to run the macro to generate all possible combinations into another sheet in the same workbook. See below what i am trying to do:

```
pivot1| pivot2|pivot3| 
|A    |D      |F     |
|B    |E      |   
|C    |

Outcome expected

|table|
|ADF  |
|AEF  |
|BDF  |
|BEF  |
|CDF  |
|CEF  |
```

Can anyone help with that?

Thank you in advance